# How do I prevent Pug from collapsing all whitespace between two tags?

Tags: pug

When I do this in a template:

```
div(class="field")
    label Password
    input(type="password")
```

I get this output:

```
<div class="field"><label>Password</label><input type="password"></div>
```

So the label and input tags have zero space between them, instead of the single space between them that they would have in a normal HTML file where they're on two different lines.

How do I get that standard single space between the two elements, in a Pug template, in the least ugly possible way? I could use CSS to fix the spacing, but that seems like a lot of verbosity to add, just to get what is a standard HTML feature when you aren't using Pug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want/expect (put exactly one space between the two elements, in the rendered HTML output).

```
div(class="field")
    label Password
    = ' '
    input(type="password")
```

Using the `=` operator at the beginning of a line allows you to insert a Javascript expression. So here, I'm inserting a string containing a single space.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#whitespace-control) demonstrates how to control whitespace using pipe characters.

```
div(class="field")
    |
    |
    label Password
    |
    |
    input(type="password")
```

This should render:

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, since the documentation mentions it. Unfortunately, it seems to have no effect in the current version of Pug. The `label` and `input` tags are still stuck together with no space between them.

Answer (score 1):

In Pug Template, a space between the elements can be added by including a **PIPELINE** ***like this-*** **|**  after an element and putting **whitespace** after the pipeline character.

Example-

```
span.price 200
| //- Whitespace included
span.person per person
```

Pipeline character allows to include content outside of the element. I hope this answer will be helpful for someone.