# Pug convert to HTML, how convert with line break?

Tags: html, gulp, pug

Pug convert in this HTML code:

```
<ul class="header__menu-list" id="header-menu">
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="catalog.html">Ювелирные изделия</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Часы</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Ручки</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Аксессуары</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Новости</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I need to generate this code, with line breaks:

```
<ul class="header__menu-list" id="header-menu">

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="catalog.html">Ювелирные изделия</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Часы</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Ручки</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Аксессуары</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Новости</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>

</ul>
```

How can I do?

Comment: Check out this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55982657/5351721

Comment: Yes, but...
Pug code will be bad - everywhere " | " ...

Need HTML converter to perform this task.

Or gulp plugin.

Comment: It's need in all HTML code.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources such as converters or plugins are generally off-topic for Stack Overflow.